# Return a union in C, but make it look nice

Tags: c, unions

So, I have a union:

```
typedef union {
    int intVal;
    char charVal;
    bool boolVal;
} myUnion_t;
```

And I have a function, `foo`, (in the same file as the latter union) which will return `myUnion_t`.
I obviously could do:

```
myUnion_t foo(int n){
    myUnion_t rtn;

    if(n == 0){
        rtn.intVal = 1;
    } else if(n == 1){
        rtn.charVal = 'b';
    } else {
        rtn.boolVal = false;
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

But this is rather messy; my CDO doesn't like it. Is there a nicer way to do this, something like:

```
myUnion_t foo(int n){
    if(n == 1){
        return 1;
    } else if(n == 2){
        return 'b';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Okay, unions are inherently messy. Thanks for your help, I'll just do it the normal way :)

Comment: "But this is rather messy" Unfortunately, unions are rather messy all by themselves.

Comment: What is "this" to find a easier way? By the way, you obviously can't do such a thing and the `object_t` as return type and type of local variable should be `union object_t`.

Comment: `union object_t` and `object_t foo(...` will not even compile successfully. `object_t` is not defined. In case it does compile, you use a C++ compiler. Either change your code or the tag.

Comment: Also a semicolon that should be after declaration of `union` iss missing.

Comment: @MikeCAT: "*obviously can't do such a thing*" refers to what please (besides the fact that `union` is missing two times)?

Comment: @alk Nothing. I just meant to point out that `union`s are missing.

Comment: If the code as shown compiles you are using C++ compiler.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Unions aren't messy, _variants_ are messy. There shouldn't be many reasons to ever use variants in C.

Comment: `object_t foo(char ch){ .... return false;}` Err, what please?

Comment: .. to add to my 2nd last comment: If you are using C++ this indeed is messy by concept. Do not use a union, but a class (or even classes), providing the necessary constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you cannot return a value of a `union` member in place of a `union` itself, you could use [*compound literals of C99*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) to avoid declaring the `union` at the top and setting its fields outside initializer:

```
typedef union object_t {
    int intVal;
    char charVal;
    _Bool boolVal;
} object_t;

object_t foo(char ch){
    switch(ch) {
        case 'a': return (object_t) { .intVal = 4 };
        case 'b': return (object_t) { .charVal = 'b' };
        default:  return (object_t) { .boolVal = true };
    }
}
```

The reason you need to use compound literal is that the type by itself is insufficient to identify the member of a `union` that you would like to be assigned.

Comment: No offense, but this is even more messy.

Comment: @Blacksilver Messiness is in the eye of the beholder. To me, this is as clean as it gets; I would definitely prefer this to setting fields of the `output`.

Comment: I want to make my code *readable*. if someone didn't know about compound literals, they wouldn't be able to read this.

Comment: @Blacksilver I would make no excuses for others reading my code who do not know the language in which they program. Compound literals have been part of the language for more than 16 years. To put this in perspective, that's three years more than C# has been around. This is more than enough time to become aware of them, and start using their expressive potential. If anything, people unfamiliar with compound literals should thank you for demonstrating a clean use of them in your code.

Comment: Style aside, I see no benefit of compound literals here. It will yield the identical machine code to what the OP already had.

Comment: "*if someone didn't know about compound literals*", so you want to make the code "simpler".

Comment: @Blacksilver If someone doesn't know about `<programming feature x>` they better go and study that feature then. You should never write code to be read by non-programmers. You should safely assume that all readers of your C code are C programmers of average competence. That being said, I agree that you shouldn't use compound literals just for the sake of it. I don't find this code any better or worse than the original.

Comment: @Lundin Absolutely - optimizing compilers will produce identical code in both instances. However, when you read `output.charVal = 'A';` in the original code you need to (1) see where `output` is declared, and (2) what happens to `output` after the chain of conditionals. The code with compound literals, on the other hand, brings everything in one place: you see how the union is constructed and that it is returned, all on a single line. That is why I think that the code with compound literals is easier to read.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'd actually buy your readability argument if you had at the same time rewritten the code as a  `switch` with every condition and return value on a single line, indented so that they line up below each other. Like `switch(ch)
{
  case 'a': return (object_t) { .intVal = 4     };
  case 'b': return (object_t) { .charVal = 'b'  };
  default:  return (object_t) { .boolVal = true };
}`  (but without SO's lack of new line characters in comments).

Comment: I think I'll just stick with the messy way. Thanks everyone for your help :)

Comment: @Lundin Well, I saw that OP commented that he could also use `switch` instead of an `if`, so I decided to stay with his `if`/`else` approach. But I would definitely use `switch` in my code because it is cleaner.

Comment: I am normally a C++ programmer. And I know about C's compound literals, variadic macros and generic selections. Therefore, I would expect non-junior C programmers about them, too.